# BottomNavigationView: Reuse fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments, bottomnavigationview

I am using `BottomnavigationView` in my app. But each time I navigate through it, `fragments get recreated`. I found that in case of `ViewPager` we can use `setOffscreenPageLimit()` for reusing fragments.

How to achieve the same in case of BottomNavigationView?

Comment: Checkout [FragNav](https://github.com/ncapdevi/FragNav) which works well with `BottomnavigationView`